# What does the port forwarding feature "port range" & "local port" do?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

My ASUS router has a a port range option in my port forwarding along with local port. Do I need to use both when port forwarding? I understand that port range is used for forwarding ports within a range, but then what is the point on local port?

Example image

[image]

When I port forward ports I use the just the port range leaving the local port empty. Is this the correct way as I have seen people use both the local port & port range for example forwarding the port 443.

In the photo above, it shows the ports 20,21 forwarded in port range, but then just 21 forwarded as a local port. Does this mean the port 20 is forwarded to port 21?

Please help enlighten me

Comment: You might change the local port if you wanted a different port used on the endpoint. For example, if you wanted all HTTP (port 80) traffic that comes into your router sent to, say, port 81 on a server on your LAN.